# Sanitizing variables in SimpleXMLElement::xpath expressions

Tags: php, xpath

I am using XPath to select XML nodes in a [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). My XPath expression is variable:

```php
$xml->xpath("a[@href = '{$some_specific_value_of_href}']");
```

Since I do not have full control over the value of the `$some_specific_value_of_href` variable, the above code is prone to an injection attack, where a malicious value of the variable will produce an arbitrary set of elements.

Most mature XML APIs, such as the [lxml library for Python](https://lxml.de/), allow the user to specify placeholder variable names in an XPath expression, and compile the XPath expression without running the risk of an injection attack:

```py
xml.xpath(
    "a[@href = $placeholder_variable_name]",  # Python performs no substitution here
    placeholder_variable_name=some_specific_value_of_href
);
```

Is there similar functionality available for PHP 7?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, related perhaps. The other question is asking how to sanitize. This question is asking whether PHP requires the programmer to sanitize, or whether there is support for pre-compiled XPath expressions.

Comment: The question and the answer are the same:  It's bad design to be passing user-providing strings into XPath expressions (accepted, correct answer) and there's sample sanitizing code (other answer) if you want to disregard the good advice to change your design.

Comment: The answer in the duplicate containing the `xpath_quote` function is probably the useful part. No, PHP doesn't have native support for a parameterised xpath query, so you'll need to do something yourself.

Comment: @kjhughes The accepted answer advises to “use pre-compiled XPath expression”. That is a fairly useless piece of advice in the context of this question, since as we have learnt, PHP does not support pre-compiled XPath expression.

Comment: The accepted answer primarily advises against what you wish to do, and the other answer there offers a way to do so if you insist.  Further, I've added a second Q/A on the topic to the duplicate box.  If you feel your answer is still distinct, please explain how.  Thanks.